# How to compare two numeric values

Tags: vbscript

My script will read a value from application.

If the value is numeric, then compare with the value 8.

If not numeric (i.e. 1,2m,kk, null, ss), return false.

**Example 1:**

```
var1 = "aa" 
If var1 > 8 then
  print "greater"
End If
```

I am not sure why it prints "greater". It should return false.

**Example 2:**

```
var1 = 10 
If var1 > 8 then
  print "greater"
End If
```

It returns true as expected.

How can it return false if var1 is not a numeric and if var1 is numeric but less than 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve what you want:

```
var1 = 4
If IsNumeric(A1) = True Then
  if(a1 < 8) then
   print "false"
  else
    print "True"
  end if
Else
  print "false"
End If
```

This does what you want

So, let me explain in case you need that:

The function isNumeric checks whether a value is numeric or not, and returns true or false depending on the results.

Since what you need to know is, if the value is numeric, I used that function for the first condition, if the value returns true, then it checks if the value in that variable is greater than 8 or not.

If the value is smaller then it prints "false" if not it prints "true".

Going back to the isNumeric function, if it returns false, it will print "false".

And thats about it.

Comment: Please accept as answer if this answer your question.